# Two Monitors to my laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors

My laptop has one VGA connector and one HDMI connector. I have two monitors that have only VGA connectors.

I would like to connect both monitors to the laptop in extended-desktop mode.

I tried a VGA splitter, but it only clones the single desktop instead of extending it.

There are HDMI-to-VGA adapters which won't work. Digital to Analog converters exists but they are fairly expensive, so I am wondering what other ways an analog VGA monitor can be connected.

Comment: What other video connectors does the laptop have? HDMI? DVI? SVideo? Composite?

Comment: one HDMI, but my monitor have only VGA, so I need a digital to analog converter which is very expensive.

Comment: @Tippu Shopping questions are off-topic, whereas this is really a technology question. I have edited your question to remove the term "cheapest" to avoid it getting closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Paul - not sure how the word cheapest will make it off-topic. I did some research and whatever I came across are expensive, so I am looking for cost effective solution. But anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: I have no idea why this question is closed even after my explanation, ohh well I can find better forums

Comment: Tippu, the only solution is to buy something. You cant fix it any other way, Im sorry.

Answer (score 4):

In the absense of any other video-out ports on your laptop, a VGA->USB adapter might work for you.

These use USB 2.0 and commonly have drivers for Windows XP up to 7.

Answer (score 2):

Well your options are fairly limited if you don't want to get a new monitor (to support the HDMI slot):

1. You could (as the other Paul said) use a USB adapter (something like [http://www.amazon.com/EVGA-100-U2-UV19-TR-Supporting-2048x1152-Resolution/dp/B003L53C2E/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003L53C2E) for instance)
2. You could try using a dock if it's supported. It would depend on your laptop, but I had a dock with a work laptop that supported two DVI ports (and you can likely for your monitor with a fairly cheap cable).